# Comparing values of an unmanaged type for bitwise equality in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitwise-operators, value-type, c#-8.0

<sup>*This question is about .NET Core 3.1 and C# 8.0 (or newer pre-release versions).*</sup>

I need to write a generic method that can compare two values of an unmanaged value type (i.e. a value type satisfying C# [`unmanaged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) constraint) for bitwise equality. I realize that some value types can have field layout with gaps, or equality semantics where values with different bit patterns are considered equal by the predefined equality operator, or vice versa, values with identical bit patterns are considered not equal. E.g.

```
using static System.BitConverter;
using static System.Console;

WriteLine(ToDouble(GetBytes(0x8000000000000000ul)) ==
          ToDouble(GetBytes(0x0000000000000000ul))); // True

WriteLine(ToDouble(GetBytes(0xFFF8000000000000ul)) ==
          ToDouble(GetBytes(0xFFF8000000000000ul))); // False
```

I am not concerned with these issues. I am interested in bitwise equality of values considered just as opaque blobs. I would prefer to avoid creating copies of data and pinning if possible. Here is my current approach:

```cs
using System;
using static System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal;

public static class BitwiseUtils
{
    public static bool BitwiseEquals<T>(in T x, in T y) where T : unmanaged
    {
        return AsBytes(CreateReadOnlySpan(ref AsRef(in x), 1)).SequenceEqual(
               AsBytes(CreateReadOnlySpan(ref AsRef(in y), 1)));
    }
}
```

It seems to be quite efficient, but looks overly verbose. Can you propose a simpler version?

Comment: you have efficient code that says what it does and does what it says ... and your problem is what exactly? ;)

Comment: It is 7 method calls (including some from scary "Unsafe" class) for simple bitwise equality of 2 values. I think I might have overlooked a simpler way... Yes, all those method calls except `SequenceEqual` are inlined by JIT, but still...

Comment: unless pointer arithmetic scares you less than some calls to unsafe classes, at least I would stay with what you have... ;)

Answer (score 0):

As long as `unmanaged` generic constraint is available, raw pointers to generic unmanaged value type can be used, as well as `sizeof`.

```cs
public unsafe static bool BitwiseEquals<T>(in T x, in T y)
where T : unmanaged
{
    fixed (T* px = &x)
    fixed (T* py = &y)
    {
        var p1 = (byte*)px;
        var p2 = (byte*)py;

        for (var i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
        {
            if (p1[i] != p2[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This way must have the highest performance that C# code could achieve and you don't worry about the method calling or inlining.

It does the same thing as `Unsafe` and `MemoryMarshal`, and using "unsafe" (either `unsafe` contexts or `Unsafe` class) is unavoidable for you need to access the raw bit data with effeciency requirement.

Don't be scared by writing C code in C# regardless of conditions, for it depends on what it does.